# await function before returning response on nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I need to await a nodejs function that runs a node-fetch requisition but it's presenting "Internal Server Error". This is a lambda function on aws and the url target is public and accessible. What I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function fetchLogin(){
  const url = 'https://www.url.../test.txt';
  const res = await fetch(url);
  return res;
}

exports.index = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const fetchResult = await fetchLogin();
  return response(200,'text/html', fetchResult);
};
```

Comment: Isn't it the url you are fetching that is returning an Internal server error ?

Comment: @HartWoom no, because I can reach it with a browser

Comment: That doesn't mean that you can do it via code...the browser will send a bunch of things like cookies and other headers. We have no idea what your `fetch` sends. If it's really exactly like this, then you don't send any headers. Perhaps you need some.

Comment: Do we have fetch api in nodejs? I think it's only available in browsers.

Comment: @h-sifat `const fetch = require('node-fetch');` at the top

Comment: @SandroBenevides try to log the result before returning the response. Also you can add a .catch() on fetchLogin(), there might be more details if an error is thrown

Comment: @VLAZ oh I see!

Comment: @HartWoom I tried to put the fetch() inside a try/catch but it returned a message saying the endpoint take too long to respond

Comment: There are lots of reasons for a request to timeout. But you need to debug by yourself why, either with a tool like Postman or directly with your browser, you can access what is being sent, which way, etc...